# Copy multiple element value and append text after in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have price span tags on my page:

```
<div>
<span class="priceTitle">10.00</span>
</div>
<div>
<span class="priceTitle">15.00</span>
</div>
<div>
<span class="priceTitle">20.00</span>
</div>
```

I want to append after the span tag the value of the span multiplied by a number.

Somehow like this:

```
$( ".priceTitle" ).after( $( ".priceTitle" ).val()*1.20 );
```

...but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` does not have a `.value` property. Use `.each()` to iterate `.priceTitle` elements, `+` operator and `.textContent` of element to convert string to number; chain `.toFixed(2)` if you are expecting decimal  and two zeroes following product of multiplication.

```js
$(".priceTitle")
.each(function() {
  $(this).after(" " + (+this.textContent * 1.20).toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="priceTitle">10.00</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="priceTitle">15.00</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="priceTitle">20.00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @FaouziOudouh Given `html` at Question, why is `parseInt` necessary?

Comment: textContent is always an integer, I don't think that parseInt is necessary here.